# Arithmetic sequence - Find term given sum of terms, a1, and d

Tags: sequences-and-series

Working on something where I've encountered the following problem: I am given the Sn (Sum of n terms) which is 689, and I know that the first 3 terms are -7, 3, and 13. This gives me the a, -7, and the d, which is 10.

The problem is, all formulas I know and have tried re-arranging aren't working out very well.

```
Sn = n/2(a - l)
```

I don't know L.

```
Sn = n/2(2a+(n-1)d)
689 = n/2(2a+(n-1)d)
1378 = n(2a+(n-1)d)
```

I don't know the N.
I've tried long-hand, adding all the numbers and came up with the 13th term being the desired 689. However, how do I get 13 with only the given information, not doing longhand as I did? What formula do I use, and re-arrange?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

Solve as normal until you have the equation in the form ax^2+bx+c=0. This is a quadratic equation and using the quadratic formula you arrive at 13. Ignore the negative value as "n" cant be negative.

Answer (score 0):

The relation between the number of terms and the first and last terms can be found by

> $a_{f}=a_{o}+n*d$

Essentially, the last term would just be expressed as the the first term (your starting point) plus however many 'steps' (i.e. - each step would be 'd' or the common ratio) are needed to get to the last term. The number of steps, as always in an arithmetic sequence would be the number of terms minus 1.

The rest, you should be able to figure out on your own. Try thinking about what the problem actually means rather than just conforming to a fixed, memorized formula.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving the way you did, try substituting the variables in to get a quadratic as follows:

$$S_n=\frac{n}{2}(2a_1+(n-1)d)$$
$$689=\frac{n}{2}(2(-7)+10(n-1))$$
$$689=\frac{n}{2}(10n-24)$$
$$689=5n^2-12n$$
$$0=5n^2-12n-689$$
$$0=(n-13)(5n+53)$$
$$n = \{13, \frac{-53}{5}\}$$

Since the number of terms cannot be negative nor fractional, you can eliminate the second solution and get that $n$ is $13$.